# GORM standalone: no updateOne() with maps

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, grails-orm

In my good'ol grails (3.1.x) app I have lines like

```
  ModuleState.collection.updateOne( 
    [ compositeKey:ck ], 
    [ $set:[ compositeKey:ck, dateUpdated:new Date(), online:true ] ], 
    [ upsert:true ] )
```

In my grails-free app with `GORM standalone`:

```
compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb:6.0.4.RELEASE'
```

this line throws an exception

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[compositeKey:111], [$set:[...]], ...]
>   Possible solutions: updateOne(org.bson.conversions.Bson, org.bson.conversions.Bson), updateOne(org.bson.conversions.Bson, org.bson.conversions.Bson, com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOptions)

so, the new map-consuming methods are not injected.

Any way to fix it and make GORM great again?

Comment: why are we using maps ? I mean $set operator takes field value pair right ?  Are you trying to pass all the key value at once ? you can easily wrap key value as bson object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb-ext:6.0.4.RELEASE` to your classpath